# Heroku crashes when I try to login or register new user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

My application works perfectly fine when used locally, but when using Heroku I fail to register, or login. Below is the errors I have had:

```
2022-04-14T09:42:38.162125+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=crypto-emissions-calculator.herokuapp.com request_id=9c770e38-15d6-4aec-8ea7-cc88a54d81f3 fwd="86.26.128.27" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=302 bytes=402 protocol=https
2022-04-14T09:42:38.202179+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/accounts/login" host=crypto-emissions-calculator.herokuapp.com request_id=6b4c5157-b8bd-4f8d-9f2c-6cfcdeb70023 fwd="86.26.128.27" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=304 bytes=151 protocol=https
2022-04-14T09:42:38.309361+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/index.css" host=crypto-emissions-calculator.herokuapp.com request_id=926d9066-9c0b-4be3-8771-6cc7d8c022c2 fwd="86.26.128.27" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=812 protocol=https
2022-04-14T09:42:59.201019+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
2022-04-14T09:42:59.201032+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:151:23)
2022-04-14T09:42:59.201033+00:00 app[web.1]:     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
2022-04-14T09:42:59.201033+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
2022-04-14T09:43:19.179894+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/accounts/login" host=crypto-emissions-calculator.herokuapp.com request_id=7329069b-ee04-4793-ac69-4a91c069abd2 fwd="86.26.128.27" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 1):

my apologies if my answer is insufficient as a first time poster. I ran into this issue as well and what helped was to go into the heroku webpage. Underneath the "more" options is "view logs". Click that and then sign in/sign up on your application. It seems that the web-based logs give greater detail and should show that the problem lies within your mongoose connection. The way to solve this is to go into your database network access and change the IP access to everywhere and that should fix it. Hope this helps.